# Можно ли прочитать данные ключа .jks?

Tags: android

Можно ли прочитать дату из файла ключа *.jks, до которой я создал ключ для подписывания приложения Android, а то я забыл. Ключей много понасоздавал и теперь я запутался

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В командной строке набрать

```
keytool -list -v -keystore <имя.jks>
```

[image]

Comment: а где лежит keytool?

Comment: @Hellraiser, для windows c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.x.xx\bin\